# A function satisfying certain properties

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I am looking for a smooth nonnegative function $f=f(x)$ defined on $(0,1)$ satisfying the following properties but having a hard time to construct, I'd appreaciate any help:

1. $\max\{|f'(x)|,|f''(x)|\}\le cf(x)$ for some constant $c$ for every $x\in (0,1)$ (desirably I want to be able to choose $c$ as small as I wish)
2. $f$ is zero on a subinterval of $(0,1)$
3. $f(x)>m$ for some $m>0$ on a subinterval of $(0,1)$.

Can such function exist?

Comment: What about $f=0$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add one more condition. I also want f to be nonnegative on (0,1) and strictly positive on a subinterval of (0,1).

Comment: Clearly, you cannot choose $c$ as small as you wish: Because of mean value theorem, we have that $|f'(x)|\ge \frac{m-0}{1-0}=m$ somewhere between the points $a,b$ where $f(a)=0$ and where $f(b)=m$, so $c>1$.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd make my comment into an answer. You write:

> $\max\{|f'(x)|,|f''(x)|\}\le cf(x)$ for some constant $c$ for every $x\in(0,1)$ (**desirably I want to be able to choose $c$ as small as I wish**)

and

> Can such function exist?

The answer is **No**:

Let $a,b\in(0,1)$ be such that $f(a)=0$ and $f(b)>0$ and assume w.l.o.g. that $a<b$. Let $b'\in(a,b]$ be such that $f(b')\ge f(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ ($b'$ exists by extreme value theorem).

Then by the mean value theorem, there is an $x\in(a,b')$ such that $f'(x) = \frac{f(b')-f(a)}{b'-a}$. But we know that $f(b')\ge f(x)$ (by choice of $b'$) and $b'-a<1$ (because $a,b'\in(0,1)$), so we obtain that $f'(x) = f(b')\frac{1}{b'-a}\ge f(x)\frac{1}{b'-a} > f(x)$.

Therefore, we cannot choose $c$ smaller (or equal) than 1, esp. not as small as we wish.